# MIT/GNU Scheme: Ill-formed clause

Tags: lisp, scheme

```
(define (u13 x y z)
(+
    (square (cond
        ((and (> x y) (> x z))) x)
        ((and (> y x) (> y z))) y)
        (else z))
    (square (cond
        ((and (> x y) (< x z))) x)
        ((and (> y x) (< y z))) y)
        (else z)))
```

Кидает ошибку. Я так понимаю ошибка во форматировании, но не могу найти.
square определенна как:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
```

Comment: (define (u13 u i o)
 (+
  (square (cond
   ((and (> x y) (> x z)) x)
   ((and (> y x) (> y z)) y)
   (else z))
  (square (cond
   ((and (> x y) (< x z)) x)
   ((and (> y x) (< y z)) y)
   (else z))) -- так она определяется, но при вызове кидает - Unbound variable: y, такой переменной у меня вообще не существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в форматировании, спас Vim:

```
(define (u13 x y z)
(+
    (square (cond
        ((and (> x y) (> x z)) x)
        ((and (> y x) (> y z)) y)
        (else z)))
    (square (cond
        ((and (> x y) (< x z)) x)
        ((and (> y x) (< y z)) y)
        (else z)))))
```

Comment: @ZX_SPECYRUM Если Lisp увлеклись стоит глянуть в сторону Emacs, slime, Guile, Common Lisp. Vim шикарный редактор но Emacs заточен как раз под лиспы из коробки.

Comment: Читал про суставодробительные комбинации в Emacs'е по этому немного побоялся. Думаю, позже. Common Lisp я планировал опробовать позже, просто увлек SICP подачей материала, достаточно романтичного подхода к описанию программирования) + далее обещали рассказать о интерпретаторах и компиляторах, меня это интерисует.